# Miniseries featuring an upside down ziggurat-shaped spaceship

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

An American made for TV movie shown over several nights in, I think, the 90's, that featured a spaceship resembling an upside down ziggurat hovering just above ground that was later discovered to have been involved in previous human evolution and threatens to destroy the current manifestation by reterraforming the planet.

My memory of this movie is very sketchy, but the first group of soldiers sent inside were killed.

I've looked all over the place and can't find any description that fits the movie.

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't match (therefore it's not an answer), but this somehow sparks thoughts on [*Stargate*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111282/).

Answer (score 6):

Was this the spaceship?

[image: Epoch poster]

If it is, the movie is [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(film)) (2001).